# SignatureDoesNotMatch error when using putObject, using Meteor and aws-sdk

Tags: amazon-web-services, meteor

I'm not quite sure what's happening here. Using the exact same credentials, and a policy that allows anything, I can effectively GET any objects I want. Creating a signed url for uploading files, however, I get the following error. I've tried creating a new set of credentials, changing the permissions on the account, using POST instead of PUT, and at this point I'm pretty confused as to why I'm getting the wrong signature.

```
<Error>
<Code>SignatureDoesNotMatch</Code>
<Message>
The request signature we calculated does not match the signature you provided. Check your key and signing method.
</Message>
<StringToSignBytes>
47 45 54 0a 0a 0a 31 34 30 35 30 34 37 35 30 36 0a 2f 64 6f 63 73 65 72 76 2f 74 65 73 74 2e 6a 70 67
</StringToSignBytes>
<RequestId>B0D5564858E39BC8</RequestId>
<HostId>
a7pcxkko4MFGbWD6WbE/pxymtOXm9UjMvYeuY0HKhMUCRkyx2H+XFH673OAsnu7RNjkzbQ/n01o=
</HostId>
<SignatureProvided>GdXhr+Md2bEyWCZIxdHRjyKbznY=</SignatureProvided>
<StringToSign>GET 1405047506 /docserv/test.jpg</StringToSign>
<AWSAccessKeyId>AKIAJTXUFSQQNFSKB4NQ</AWSAccessKeyId>
</Error>
```

Here's the serverside function that I'm calling to generate the signed URL. Again, I've tested and know that the credentials allow me to GET and do other actions correctly.

```
function insertDocS3(fileName){

    if(Meteor.settings.AWS){
        AWS.config.update({'accessKeyId': Meteor.settings.AWS.accessKeyId, 
            'secretAccessKey': Meteor.settings.AWS.secretAccessKey});
    } else{
        console.log("AWS Settings Missing");
    }
    s3 = new AWS.S3();
    var key = fileName;

    var params = {Bucket: "docserv", Key: key};
    var url = s3. getSignedUrl('putObject', params);
    console.log("The URL is: ", url);

    return url;
}
```

Here's the client-side code that calls the server function, and uses AJAX to PUT the file:

```
uploadToS3 = function(){

    var allFiles = $('input[type=file]').get(0).files;
    for(var i = 0; i< allFiles.length; i++){
        fd = new FormData();
        fd.append(allFiles.item(i).name, "string");

        var filename = allFiles.item(i).name.split('\\').pop();

        Meteor.call('insertDocS3', filename, function(error, result){
            $.ajax({
                type:"POST",
                url: result,
                data: fd,
                processData: false,
                success:function(response){
                    alert("succeeded");
                }
            });

        });


    }
}
```

And for good measure, here's the policy that I'm using for this set of credentials:

```
{
  "Version": "2012-10-17",
  "Statement": [
    {
      "Effect": "Allow",
      "Action": "*",
      "Resource": "*"
    }
  ]
}
```